# Laravel separate foreach values with '-'

Tags: php, laravel-4, explode, laravel-blade

I'm trying to separate these values: `Administrator Hoofd-Moderator Proef-Moderator VIP Donateur Lid` with an line `-`.

The problem is, what I do, it doesn't work. So what can I do to let it work?

My view:

```
@foreach(Stats::GetRoles() as $role)
<b style="color:{{ $role->colour }};">{{ $role->name }}</b> -
@endforeach
```

My Controller (Stats.php)

```
public static function GetRoles()
    {
        return Role::orderBy('id', 'desc')->remember(500)->get();
    }
```

I work with such a function because it is IMO handy.

So I want to get a list like this:

`Administrator - Hoofd-Moderator - Proef-Moderator - VIP - Donateur - Lid`

With the color of course.

Thanks!

Comment: So what are you getting currently?

Comment: Now, I just get the list like it stands in the question. just like this: http://prntscr.com/7z5yr4

Comment: Isn't it a cache issue? (I don't know Laravel so not sure.)

Comment: No it isn't I looked for it ;)

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a hack job, but try like this:

```
@foreach(Stats::GetRoles() as $role)
<b style="color:{{ $role->colour }};">{{ $role->name. " - " }}</b>
@endforeach
```

I personally would use the implode function if you want to concatenate them all in a line.

Comment: I don't want to get at the end the '-' I know I can do it lik that, but I don't want to get the `-`for the latest item.

Comment: Definitely implode with " - " as glue.

Comment: How should my code must be then? Because the implode function doens't work when I try to use it.

Comment: show how you are implementing implode, then we'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I just do this: http://laravel.io/bin/1y0yP but then I got this error: `implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

Comment: When I use `implode(" - ", (array)$role->name)` It doesn't display an error, but it doesn't show te `-` either.